# How to wrap the Text around the image using Bootstrap "flex" classes, strictly not using floats?

Tags: image, bootstrap-4

How to wrap the Text around the image using Bootstrap "flex" classes, strictly not using floats?

Like this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your image:
[image]

Comment: yes, it works but i am saying using Bootstrap "flex" classes not using float property.